# Enable multi region write Cosmos DB for subset of regions

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, geo-replication

Is it possible to enable multi-region write for Azure Cosmos DB only for a subset of regions? So have 5 read regions but only 3 of those as write regions for example? I'd assume this would save costs but can't find that this is possible. When I enable multi-region write it just makes a read and write region of every region I add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Enabling multi-region writes makes every region writable in Cosmos DB.